# Where do files in shared folders go when deleted?

Tags: delete, trash, sharing

I have a shared folder between ubuntu users , this shared files contains files for my company work , if a user delete a file ( normal delete not <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>) .

Where does this file go , what solution should I have?

Comment: are you using samba share?

Comment: If stuff gets deleted in Ubuntu doesn't it go to /dev/null?

Answer (score 4):

If You delete files, the files are gone forever

Assuming You're using samba as your sharing server.

There's a stackable VFS module in Samba called "recycle"

> What it basically does, is instead of actually deleting the file, it
>   moves it to another directory that you specify. This allows you to get
>   the file back to them that's as current as the time that they deleted
>   it, rather than from the previous night's backup.

To install vfs:

```
sudo apt-get install samba-vfs
```

To enable it edit your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and

```
[Docs]
read only = no
path = /mnt/array/docs
write list = @users
force directory mode = 770
force create mode = 660
valid users = @users
inherit acls = Yes
inherit permissions = Yes
vfs objects = full_audit recycle
config-file = /etc/samba/recycle.conf
recycle:repository = /mnt/recycle/%u
recycle:directory_mode = 770
recycle:keeptree = Yes
recycle:versions = Yes
recycle:touch_mtime = yes
full_auditrefix = %u|%I
full_audit:success = open mkdir rmdir write unlink rename
full_audit:failure = mkdir rmdir write unlink rename
```

and here's the /etc/samba/recycle.conf file contents:

```
##Recycle Bin Configuration File##
name = Recycle Bin
mode = KEEP_DIRECTORIES|VERSIONS|TOUCH
maxsize = 0
exclude = *.o|*.obj|~$*|*.~??|*.log|*.trace
excludedir = /mnt/array/misc|/tmp|/temp|/cache
noversions = *.dat|*.ini
```

[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/samba-recycle-bin-tip-723004/)

Answer (score 0):

They are still written on your hard drive, the computer just doesn't know they are there. The file will be written on the hosts HDD. You may be able to get some recovery application to get back the file. But if people are writing on the drive often, then it will probably have been over-written.